# Electron store my app datas in 'userData' path

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, user-data

I'm building and trying do deploying a packaged electron app. FOr the packaging i used

- `electron-packager`
- `electron-installer-debian`
- `electron-installer-dmg`
- `electron-winstaller`

and I'm facing a little issue where I have to store tha appa datas somewhere in my user computer.

I saw that the good practice is to use the the folder in the path that is returned by the electron method `app.getPath('userData')`.

from the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/all#appgetpathname)
It is The directory for storing the app's configuration files, which by default it is the `appData` directory appended with the app name.

```
%APPDATA% on Windows
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME or ~/.config on Linux
~/Library/Application Support on macOS
```

By my tests sometimes this folder is not created automatically when the app is installed and other times yes and I'm wondering if i should create it or not.

Right now i'm quitting the app if this folder isn't present in the pc with the following code

```
var DatasPath = app.getPath('userData')
if (!fs.existsSync(DatasPath)){
      process.exit()
  }
```

So the question is

- should i create the `DatasPath` folder with `fs.mkdirSync(DatasPath);` when it is not present or it is 'bad practice to do so', and if I can create the folder i have to warning the user the i have just added that folder?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is impossible to say what might be causing a crash. Post your code.

Comment: @NoGrabbing Sorry for the bad explanation, the crash was an intentional crash caused by the 
Absence of this folder. i don't know if i'm supposed to create it or not so i automatically make th app quit if there is not that folder.

Answer (score 5):

*(Expanding my reply from a "comment" to an "answer")*

> i don't know if i'm supposed to create it or not so i automatically
>   make the app quit if there is not that folder

It seems you are taking "userData" too literally? It is not an actual "folder" named "userData – it is a path to where the operating system stores data for **that** application. `Electron` currently runs on 3 operating systems and each one does things differently. For our convenience, Electron hides those differences by creating the wrapper method [app.getPath(name)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname) so the same code will work on each OS.

Try this: put the line below in your `main.js` script:

```
console.log(app.getPath('userData'));
```

> /Users/*********/Library/Application Support/MyCoolApp

(the "*********" will be your user account name.)

**UPDATED:**

Run the code below in `main.js` and then look in the folder specified by the "userData" path

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require('path');
var datasPath = app.getPath('userData')
var data = "I am the cheese"
var filePath = path.join(datasPath, "savedData.txt")
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, data)
```

Comment: ok, it is a path to a folder where the os store the datas for the application, but if this folder is not automatically created by the os am i supposed to create it or not? I need a place where to store my datas and as i read the good pratice is to use that folder, but what i have to do if there isn't that folder?

Comment: You misunderstand. Try what I suggested above,

Comment: Actually I know that that line of code returns a path that change from os to os, but i don't understand how it can helps me.. I changed the question body maybe now it is more clear

Comment: still not understanding what you are trying to say.. Ok the file is created in that path but if that path didn't actually exists when someone downlads my app what i have to do. Are you trying to say that the path returned from electron always exists and i'm missing something else?

Comment: @Mat.C - you are **way** overthinking this. `Electron` creates a "userData" for every app. Trust that and move on.

Comment: also if the app is packaged? I'm 100% sure that the apps quit becouse the statement `!fs.existsSync(DatasPath)` is true

Answer (score 1):

At `pathConfig.js`

```
function getAppDataPath() {
  switch (process.platform) {
    case "darwin": {
      return path.join(process.env.HOME, "Library", "Application Support", "myApp");
    }
    case "win32": {
      return path.join(process.env.APPDATA, "myApp");
    }
    case "linux": {
      return path.join(process.env.HOME, ".myApp");
    }
    default: {
      console.log("Unsupported platform!");
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
}

const appPath = __dirname;
const appDataPath =
  !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? getAppDataPath() // Live Mode
    : path.join(appPath, "AppData"); // Dev Mode

if (!fs.existsSync(appDataPath)) {
    // If the AppData dir doesn't exist at expected Path. Then Create
    // Maybe the case when the user runs the app first.
    fs.mkdirSync(appDataPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In each operating system the appData folder has a different path and the perfect way of getting this path is by calling app.getPath('userData') in the main process.
But there is a package that can handle this for you, it stores data in a JSON file and update it in every change.
In my opinion this package is much better than handling everything by your self.
Read more :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-data-holder

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify : Actually appdata/yourApp or Application Support/yourApp etc..

Will be created **for sure** because it is holding a lot of files and folders used by Chromium and ElectronJs to work.
Like caches, cookies etc...

**/Users/home/Library/Application Support/MyApp :**

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).